# Where to give the Client ID for the google fit android application

Tags: google-fit

Im trying to put my hands in the Google Fit application recently and tried the steps given in the [Google Fit developer site](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started). And used the code given in the Android sample [BasicSensorApi](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/samples)  in the eclipse. Everytime I run the application I get the user account to log in but signing fails with the error(Error signing in the specified account. Please choose a different account.). I have generated a Client ID as specified in the developer get started link. But not sure what to be given for the android name to use the fitness api in the manifest file. Can anyone please help me to resolve the error.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for my question, I have made a small mistake in the client id generation.

Sorry for posting a wrong question.

Comment: so.. how did you do that?

Comment: You don't have to do anything with the client ID. The SHA-1 fingerprint will identify the client for you.